# BIMI logo not showing in any clients

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

We implemented the VMC/BIMI last week, and all the checks are now passing green on https://bimigroup.org/bimi-generator/ - with the logo visible in **BIMI SVG Image** in the bottom of the page.

However, even though it is one week since the DNS has been updated, and the files uploaded, the image is still not showing in a.o. Gmail and Apple inboxes - which should be email clients supporting BIMI logos.

The DNS record is added as *default._bimi.e.example.com* - which is our SAP domain. But as Content Builder doesn't support neither PEM nor SVG files, both are hosted on *example.com*. Could this be an issue, since Google states following in their [troubleshooting tips](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10911432?hl=en):

> The public web server is in the same domain as the domain where you
> added the DNS TXT record for BIMI.

Could it potentially be an issue with the SVG file, despite it being shown correctly in the BIMI Validator?

Did anyone manage to enable BIMI on an SFMC SAP domain and has some advice on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth:
Here is what I know, but I can no longer reproduce it all from past implementations. No exact answer, but might help narrow it down.

BIMI string / logo hosting

`String: v=BIMI1;l=https://www.example.com/logo.svg`.

with SAP Subdomain "mails.example.com".

so: your svg hosting should be exactly fine.

Support material:

> DMARC: The DMARC record needs to be explicitly published at the
> subdomain level (not trickle down from the top level domain). The
> DMARC policy needs to be p=reject or p=quarantine. A policy of p=none
> does not qualify for BIMI based on the BIMI guidelines.
>
> Secured Image:  The square image has to be an SVG file and hosted on
> an SSL server (https, not http). Marketing Cloud does not host SVG
> files currently, so this would need to be hosted on your own SSL
> server.
>
> Yahoo Beta Opt-in: This process is automatic. Once your DMARC and BIMI
> record are in place, your logo / image should begin to appear after a
> few weeks of sending. The image appearing is volume based, the volume
> required is not disclosed by Yahoo.
>
> Gmail: Regarding Gmail, BIMI, or brand icon will display in Gmail
> webmail - it may not immediately show at Gmail as the requirement is
> not disclosed by Google.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384413&type=1

Comment: Thank you Jonas. So just to clarify: I am requesting VMC for my SAP domain - i.e. e.example.com. Adding the DNS record for BIMI should happen on the DNS zone for my SAP subdomain (and not on parent domain). Hosting PEM/SVG on parent domain (example.com) should not be an issue. If that's the fact, my current implementation should be according to best practice - and still the logo is not showing. Strange.